# Using HoldLock Incorrectly in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, locks

I believe I am using `HOLDLOCK` incorrectly.

The reason I think this is because I have a table that acts like a queue. The queue receives its items from the SQL below and gets processed, one by one in a console application. I haven't tested yet but I believe when this console application starts processing this table, during some of the long selects the code below fails.  Why do I think that...because I am logging the GameID when grabbing everything from the table queue and processing them one by one in that console application. The funny thing is the games that I believe didn't make it through didn't make it in the log, therefore I dont believe they are being inserted in my queue table and I believe it's because of the `HOLDLOCK` below.

Thoughts?

```
MERGE Test WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS GL
USING (SELECT @GameId AS ID) AS NewTest ON GL.ID = NewTest.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(
    Id,
    FailedAttempts,
    DateCreated
)
VALUES
(
    NewTest.ID,
    0,
    SYSDATETIME()
);
```

Comment: Why are you using MERGE here at all?

Comment: Because I only want to insert if it's not already in the table, it very well maybe the MERGE.

Comment: Or simply INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS

Comment: @AaronBertrand http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx

Comment: @Laurence I'm well aware of that blog post. Can you provide some more context so I understand your point? Are you suggesting that MERGE is the only way to avoid race conditions?

Comment: I believe I got this code from that blog post.

Comment: @MikeFlynn that doesn't explain why you're using MERGE for something that could only ever amount to an insert. But that's okay, I'll bow out, you keep blindly using code samples you got from a blog post without understanding why you're using them... have fun!

Comment: @AaronBertrand Only that it doesn't make any practical difference, but I find the locking rules are easier to remember with the merge.

Comment: @Laurence I have a better time with transactions and isolation levels than using cumbersome MERGE syntax when it isn't necessary. YMMV.

Comment: I believe I wanted to do merge to lock the table before an insert to make sure it wasnt in there yet.  I assume this is better then a select exists.

Comment: Here is your select exists article and the issue, http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx

Comment: @MikeFlynn I get that. And you can control "the issue" in the *same way*. So why you would opt for complicated `MERGE` syntax, and blame your current problem on that, instead of using a regular `INSERT`, is absolutely beyond me. Have fun.

Comment: Personally, here I'd just do an insert and stop if I got a duplicate key exception.

Comment: Any downside to that?  Just let it fail and not handle it?

Comment: Please read http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling, http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/ and http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/ - and please, stop making assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, why not post an answer with the insert exists and try catch links so I can accept it.  Maybe a link to the merge issues also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your issue is unrelated to your use of `MERGE` or `HOLDLOCK`. I see no reason to introduce cumbersome `MERGE` syntax here, since it provides no benefit, and [especially given the potential issues it can cause in other areas](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/?utm_source-AaronBertrand). I suggest a very simple `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT dbo.Test(Id, FailedAttempts, DateCreated)
  SELECT @GameId, 0, SYSDATETIME()
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Test WITH (HOLDLOCK) 
    WHERE Id = @GameId
  );
```

I'd prefer this over just blindly trying to insert and getting a PK violation for the reasons outlined [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling) and [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/?utm_source-AaronBertrand) - in almost all cases, forcing SQL Server to try and get an exception instead of checking yourself first will yield worse performance.